# Depth first search through JSON response object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object response of varying depth. If I need to find a leaf node and trace the path of that leaf node from the parent node in java script using a depth first algorithm. How can I implement this using an array data structure?

Comment: Well I would recommend doing some research and come back when you get stuck.  People are not on here to do your homework..

Comment: What exactly is the problem?